# Reduce $F(x,y)=0$ to canonical form of parabola

Tags: analytic-geometry

I know, from calculating $\delta$ and $\Delta$, that the following function represents parabola.

$$x^2-2xy+y^2-2x+27y+10=0$$

But how can I get it to its canonical form: $y^2=2px$ ?

Essentially I need to sketch it, not precisely draw it.

Comment: Do you just need a sketch of the parabola, or do you need all the math that led to it? Do you know about diagonalization of matrices, and/or eigenvectors? Do you know about "completing the square"? Answers to these questions will help us to help you.

Comment: I do need the math behind it. I know about completing the square.

Comment: http://www.sosmath.com/CBB/viewtopic.php?t=17029

Comment: You could use matrices and then work out the affine transformation you need to get to the canonical form.

As of now, you have the equation $p(x,y)=x^2-2xy+y^2+27y+10$; your parabola is essentially $P=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R^2} | p(x,y)=0\}$. If we let $A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 & 0 \\ -1 & 1 & \frac{27}{2} \\ 0 & \frac{27}{2} & 10\end{pmatrix}$, then $P=\{(x,y,1)\in\mathbb{R^2} | (x,y,1)A\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ 1\end{pmatrix} = 0\}$. 

You want $M$ such that $M^tAM=B$ and $y^2-2px=(x,y,1)B\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ 1\end{pmatrix} = 0$. M represents the affine transformation you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. Well, your first three terms are just $(x-y)^2$. That suggests changing variables to 
$$
u = (x+y) \\
v = (x - y)
$$
which means that 
$$
x = (u+v)/2\\
y = (u - v)/2,
$$
so that you have
$$
v^2 - 2x + 2y + 25y + 10 = 0\\
v^2+2 (y-x) + 25 y + 10 = 0\\
v^2 - 2v + 25 (u-v)/2 + 10  = 0 \\
$$
That's now something for which you can do the completing-the-square to get an aligned parabola.